# Xamarin HttpClient не работает с httpS

Tags: c#, https, xamarin, httpclient

```
try
{                               
   var url = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
   var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

   var response = await client.GetAsync(url);  //<-- error                
   var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

Работает для http, но для https получаю ошибку:

> Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has
>   failed.)

Что бы решить проблему установил настройки в соответствии с: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/transport-layer-security?tabs=windows

Что не помогло. И использовал [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient)

```
   try
    {                               
       var url = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
       var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());//<-- error   

       var response = await client.GetAsync(url);               
       var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
```

И получил новую ошибку:

> Constructor on type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' not found.

Приложение запускаю через Live Player, но не думаю что это важно...

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

[image: В свойствах проекта попробуй настроить HttpClient]

В свойствах проекта попробуй настроить HttpClient

Comment: да, так и делал, не помогло